# MySQL Error 1062 after reboot node in multi master replication

Tags: mysql, multi-master

I setup 2 MySQL Community Server (8.0.20) with a replication master to master. Today one of the nodes went down, and when it went up, the replication failed. I tried to just ignore a registry with `SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;`, but the errors keep coming in.

This is the status log of the particular node that failed:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: database_1
                  Master_User: replicador
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000122
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 217195469
               Relay_Log_File: 33afd376b907-relay-bin.000105
                Relay_Log_Pos: 2829
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000122
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1062
                   Last_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table gc57125800.ate_logs; Duplicate entry '49328847' for key 'ate_logs.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log mysql-bin.000122, end_log_pos 188792316
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 188791943
              Relay_Log_Space: 28407134
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
               Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table gc57125800.ate_logs; Duplicate entry '49328847' for key 'ate_logs.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log mysql-bin.000122, end_log_pos 188792316
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: bef45e1b-99d6-11ea-a355-3e2547e4f083
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: 
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 201029 17:59:51
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not sure what I should do. Should I dump the another master and do it all over again? Do I need to do this every time a server fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html) to see the differences between the source and the replica. If the differences are many, importing data again from the source could be the fastest solution. Otherwise, you could restart MySQL with `--slave-skip-errors=1062`, fix the errors with [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html), and then restart MySQL normally.

To understand how these tools work and how they are used, take a look at this article: [MySQL replication primer with pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/08/12/mysql-replication-primer-with-pt-table-checksum-and-pt-table-sync/).

You may also want to take a look at another tool called [twindb-table-compare](https://pypi.org/project/twindb-table-compare/), which is complementary to pt-table-checksum. It reads the diffs generated by pt-table-checksum on the source and on the replica, and prints them in a format that is easier to understand, similar to the output of Linux utility `diff`.

Comment: Well, I am generating a new dump from my master server, when it's finished, i will try to ignore the 1062 errors and see if my database will stay consistent. I still don't understand what went wrong when i accidentally shutdown the server. It's a common thing to happen?

Comment: If you get a 1062 error the DB is not consistent and the problem should be fixed with the tools I mentioned (or with a new backup as you did). No, it's not common, but there may be several causes. Some of them can be avoided by setting read_only=1 on the replicas.

Comment: nitpick: twindb-table-compare is a complementary tool that is supposed to work with pt-table-checksum, not an alternative to it.

pt-table-checksum answers a question - is my relica in-sync with the master?
twindb-table-compare tells what exectly the difference is.

Comment: @nitpick Yeah, it makes pt-table-checksum human-readable. I oversimplified to avoid disgressions, but I ended up writing something wrong. I'll fix it, thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score -1):

First stop traffic from restarted node and enable slave-skip-errors 1062 on same node.
Once in sync then you should use pt-table-checksum which will provide difference between tables.

Then you need to take action accordingly.

Comment: This seems to be simply repeating a previously posted answer. If you feel your advice is different, may be you could highlight the difference?